# Не добавляется ключ при выборе файла с ключом протокола ssh2 в FileZilla

Tags: ssh

Пытаюсь подключить бота к серверу, и столкнулся с проблемой. В PuTTygen создал ключ, соответственно сохранил файл с приватным и с открытым. В FileZilla создавал "Новый сайт", и он ругался при добавлении ключа, что протокол ключа нужен SSH2, а не SSH1. Собственно, сгенерировал ключ SSH2, но FileZilla просто не загружает его, ничего не происходит. При попытке добавления левых файлов каких-то ругается, а при добавлении нужного с ключом просто ничего не меняется
[image]
[image: выбираю файл с ключом SSH2]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]